If $x + y \equiv x^2 + y^2 \equiv x^3 + y^3 \pmod{n}$, is it true that $x+y \equiv x^4 + y^4 \pmod{n}$?
If $x + y \equiv x^2 + y^2 \equiv x^3 + y^3  \pmod{n}$, is it true that $x+y \equiv x^4 + y^4  \pmod{n}$?  I have verified this by computer up to $n = 500$. Can someone furnish a proof for an arbitrary positive integer $n$?
I was computing the number of solutions to $x + y \equiv x^2 + y^2 \equiv x^3 + y^3  \pmod{n}$ for small values of $n$ and decided to try to extend to the number of solutions of $x + y \equiv x^2 + y^2 \equiv x^3 + y^3 \equiv x^4+y^4 \pmod{n}$. I noticed the number of solutions didn't change. Thus my question.

To the OP: As the question stands, it lacks context as mandated by community policy. As such, it is prone to get closed -- having 2 close votes at the point of writing for lack of context. I recommend expanding the question to include necessary context.

@Sahaj: I don't know what to add. It is just something I noticed when doing some calculations and was looking for a proof of. And thanks to you I now have one. It's all just pure mathematics. Isn't that enough?

If anything, you could add what the context of your calculations was, your computer code, etc. I personally believe the question is fine, but some do not think so.

Let $P_n = x^n + y^n$ for some integer $n\geq 1$. Also let $e_2 = xy$. We have, via Newton-Girard identities that:
$$\begin{align}
P_2 &= -2e_2 + P_1^2 \\
P_3 &= -P_1e_2 + P_2P_1 \\
P_4 &= -P_2e_2 + P_3P_1
\end{align}$$
We are given that $$P_1 \equiv P_2 \equiv P_3 \equiv k \pmod n$$
It follows that $P_4\equiv -\color{red}{P_2}e_2 + \color{red}{P_3P_1}\equiv -\color{red}{k}e_2 + \color{red}{k^2} \equiv -P_1e_2 + P_2P_1\equiv P_3\pmod n$. It follows that $k\equiv  P_4\pmod n$.
Generally for any two variables the power sum is $P_n = P_1P_{n-1} -e_2P_{n-2}$. Given that $P_1\equiv P_2\equiv P_3 \equiv k \pmod n$, it follows via strong induction that $P_r\equiv k \pmod n$ for $r\geq 4$.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to PSQs & dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
